# Setting system properties from command line but not able to access it in my step definition file

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, test-runner

Command:

> mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--name 'Approve Rejected Creative'"
> -DEnvironment="Prod"

Feature file :

```
Given User launch "<Environment>" preflight
          When User enters Email as "zzzz" and Password as "zzzz"
          Then Click on Login
          When User approves <creativeNumber> creative starting from row <startRow>
          Then the creative should be approved
```

Step Def:

```
public void launchPreflight(String Env) {
        // Set up WebDriver and launch the preflight URL
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
                "/chromedriver/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        Env = System.getProperty("Environment");
        if(Env.contains("Prod") || Env.contains("prod") || Env.contains("PROD")) {
        driver.get(Prod_URL);
        }
```

Getting below error :
Errors:
[ERROR]   Cannot invoke "String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)" because "Env" is null

I tried setting properties in the testrunner file but still the same. Am I missing something here, I am new to this code.

Comment: Could you try to put the variables BEFORE the "test" in your command line ?

Comment: Setting properties in test runner won't work. Show us the feature file and step definition.

Answer (score 0):

In scenario, you parameterized "Enviromnent"

```
Given User launch "<Environment>" preflight
```

but you are assigning environment value to null(Env is null).

```
 Env = System.getProperty("Environment");
```

Update in below way,

**Scenario**

```
Given User launch Environment preflight
```

**Code**

```
   public void launchPreflight() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/chromedriver/chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    String env = System.getProperty("Environment");
    if(env.toLowerCase().contains("prod")) {
    driver.get(Prod_URL);
    }
```

Comment: @AshutoshDas if I answered your question correctly. Please accept the answer.